# this is not updating even tho there are no reported errors in this php or sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here is the page that is supposed to allow a logged in member to transfere an amount they choose to another user on the system i have been working on this for days and found little about it online that actually helps and only found a few snippets here and there that used prepared statements which failed when i edited it so i want to keep it all mysqli for now until i understand prepared statements better or i learn OOP Or PDO but for now i mainly wish to find out why this failes when it sais it works successfully and when i cant see any errors with this code also i have edited this many times so i have tryed various ways but i must be missing something i have also included the db_conx page as a line in this code and the other included line is just to do with checking if a user is logged in, any ideas what may be wrong with this as its not working.

```
    <form name="username" method="post" action="index.php"> 
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Transfere To Username"/> <br />
    <input type="text" name="amount" placeholder="Amount To Send" style="centered"/><br />
    <input type="submit"  value="continue"/>
    </form>
   <?php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
echo "<p><br>";
echo "Logged In As $username";
echo "<p><br>";
include_once("../../../php_includes/check_login_status.php");
require("db_conx.php");
if (isset($_POST["username"]) && !empty($_POST["amount"])) {
$username2 = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['username']);
$amount = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9.]#i', '', $_POST['amount']);
$amount = (int)$amount;
$select_result = ("SELECT balance FROM users WHERE username = '$username' LIMIT 1") or die(mysqli_error($select_result));
$user_query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $select_result);
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($user_query);
if ($numrows < 1) {
echo "Error Selecting Data Try <a href=\"index.php\">Again </a> Or Go <a href=\"../index.php\">Back</a>";
}
while ($select = mysqli_fetch_array($select_result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
$available_balance = $select["balance"];
}
if($available_balance>=$amount){
$result = ("UPDATE users SET balance = balance - '$amount' WHERE username = '$username' LIMIT 1") or die(mysqli_error($result));
$user_query2 = mysqli_query($db_conx, $result);
$numrows2 = mysqli_affected_rows();
if ($numrows2 < 1) {
echo "Error Updating Data Try <a href=\"index.php\">Again </a> Or Go <a href=\"../index.php\">Back</a>";
}
$result2 = ("UPDATE users SET balance = balance + '$amount' WHERE username = '$username2' LIMIT 1") or die(mysqli_error($result2));
$user_query3 = mysqli_query($db_conx, $result2);
$numrows3 = mysqli_affected_rows();
if ($numrows3 < 1) {
echo "Error Updating Data Try <a href=\"index.php\">Again </a> Or Go <a href=\"../index.php\">Back</a>";
}}
echo "Amount Of $amount Has Been Transferred To $username2";   
} else {  
echo "No Amount Has Been Set, Try Again Or Go <a href=\"../index.php\">Back</a>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Your inattention to spelling, capitalization, and punctuation makes you appear like someone who doesn't care about their work.

Answer (score 0):

- Don't put table names in single quotes. Single quotes are for string literals and date literals.

  ```
  SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE 'username' = $username -- WRONG

  SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' -- BETTER, BUT INSECURE

  SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? -- BEST
  ```

  The same is true for your UPDATE statements. Don't quote table names or column names, but do quote strings.
- For good examples of using prepared queries with parameters, the most popular and frequently-referenced post on StackOverflow about this is [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
- Check the return value from mysqli_query(). It will be **false** if there's a problem. If it returns false, then check mysqli_error() to find out what the problem is. For example, putting a quoted string where a table name should be.

  If you don't want to write code after each mysqli_query() to check the return value, you can just configure mysqli to [throw an exception](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php) when an error occurs. Just do this once at the top of your PHP file, it'll remain in effect for the rest of the script.

  ```
  mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
  ```
- You should understand the difference between [mysqli_num_rows()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php) and [mysqli_affected_rows()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php). mysqli_num_rows() counts the rows in the result set from a SELECT, and it only works *after* you have fetched the rows. Whereas mysqli_affected_rows() counts the rows changed by an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE.

  Checking the result from mysqli_affected_rows(), you may find that your UPDATEs are changing zero rows. This happens either if the WHERE clause matches no rows (that is, there is no user for $username or $username2), or if the SET clause specifies values that result in no change to the column. You should make sure $amount is not 0.

Comment: ok i added that line to the top and also took out the ' but still no error and still not working, i wish to keep it mysqli as i said any ideas please???

Comment: See additional tips above. Also, if mysqli_report() isn't working, then you should check the result of each mysqli_query() for **false**.

Comment: Ok i added a part to check all individual queries to see affected rows for error checking and they all passed with no errors but the balance still does not transfere and i have no idea why, i am thinking of going back to mysql at this rate i been working on this for days and my head hurts can any one write an alternative that they know will work so i can test as my database and connection to it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you have not. Try to get meaningful errors from database results and requests.

```
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($user_query) or die(mysql_error()) ;
$select = mysqli_fetch_array($select_result, MYSQLI_ASSOC) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote this and got it working with the following, thanks for all your help (everyone who replied)

```
<form name="username" method="POST" action="index.php" autocomplete="off"> 
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Transfer To Username"/> <br />
<input type="text" name="amount" placeholder="Amount To Send" style="centered"/><br />
<input type="submit"  value="continue"/>
</form>
<?php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
echo "<p><br>";
echo "Logged In As $username";
echo "<p><br>";
include_once("db_conx.php");
if (isset($_POST["username"]) && !empty($_POST["amount"])) {
$username2 = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['username']);
$amount = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9.]#i', '', $_POST['amount']);
$amount = (int)$amount;
$sql = ("SELECT balance FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND balance >= $amount");
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query) or die(mysql_error());
if ($numrows < 1) {
echo "<h3>Failed To Complete </h3>"; 
}
else {
echo "Amount Of $amount Has Been Transferred To $username2 You May Now Go <a href=\"../index.php\">Back</a>";
$sql = ("UPDATE users SET balance = balance - '$amount' WHERE username = '$username' LIMIT 1");
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
$sql = ("UPDATE users SET balance = balance + '$amount' WHERE username = '$username2' LIMIT 1");
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query) or die(mysql_error());
if ($numrows < 1) {
echo "<h3>Failed To Complete Transfer! Try Again Or Go <a href=\"../index.php\">Back</a></h3>"; 
}
else {
echo "<h3>Failed To Complete Transfer! Try Again Or Go <a href=\"../index.php\">Back</a></h3> ";
}
}
}
?>
<a href="../index.php">Back To Balance Page</a></h3>
```